PyTelegramBot Бот в телеге. Рандомные картинки
Пробовал различные методы из интернета, но настроить бота на отправку случайной картинки из папки не получилось. Максимум, что получилось, это примерно правильно написать, но выдает ошибку [WinError 3]. Код где-то отсюда же брал, но он не рабочий, пробовал через glob, тоже не робит.
Кто шарит, помогите пж, а то я уже полдня не могу найти ничего.
@bot.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def cat(message):
    photo22 = open(random.choice(os.listdir('papka')), 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo22)

Выдает в терминале

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '3JNLv6PoEMk.jpg'

Где в кавычках картинка, которую должен был отправить. Код по рандомайзеру работает, но не отправляет картинку (всегда разные jpg файлы в ошибке).

Ну так listdir возвращает названия файлов, а не пути: нужно добавить путь до папки. photo22 = open('papka/' + random.choice(os.listdir('papka')), 'rb')

Пасиб, помогло. Я вынес папку из папки своего проекта. Если папка находится в папке, то слева надо прописать путь к папке и потом к папке, которая мне нужна? Я прописывал в начале путь к папке проекта, потом к моей папке с картинками и выдавало ошибку

Если необходимая папка находится не в папке запуска файла, то используйте абсолютный путь:
directory_path="D:/ПУТЬ/К/ПАПКЕ/" замените D на свой диск. После: photo22 = open(directory_path + random.choice(os.listdir(directory_path)), 'rb')

оо, пасибо, запишу себе это в блокнотик
